# Predicting Ingredients amount for getting color

Tags: machine-learning

I have a dataset of different colors and the ingredients (with amount in grams) that was used to make that color
My intention is to build an ML model that would take the color values (eg. RGB/LAB) as input and gives me the amount of each ingredients that would be needed to mix and get that color. Some of the ingredients can have 0 values indicating that they were not used to make that color. My input (L, A and B) are the only features I have for now and there are about 2,000 observations. Example dataset is below:

[image]

I am a beginner and finding my way into machine learning. Please suggest what algorithm would best fit my purpose.

Comment: How many observations do you have? You're showing 4 rows, so do you only have 4 observations?

Comment: I have about 2,000 observations

Comment: Edit that into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to begin is treat each of the dependent variables (DVs, or ingredients, in this case) as a separate problem. So then you have six modeling problems (or five, if the sum of the ingredients is fixed) with three predictors apiece. For each DV, compute the SD, compare it to the cross-validated root mean square error (RMSE) of ordinary linear regression with the three predictors, and if that RMSE isn't good enough, look into fancier models like decision trees.